# Nested queries using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm using collection ***espData*** which contains documents of the following type:

```
{ 
 mac: String,
 hash: String,
 rssi: Number
}
```

Using Mongoose I want to select those lines with same mac and same hash and if the count(*) is equal to 2 then the line is selected. Then I want to perform an aggregation which return mac and the respectively average of the rssi.

I made this piece of code but it doesn't work.

```
EspDataModel.aggregate([
    { $group: {
      _id:{
        mac:"$mac",
        hash:"$hash",
      },
      count: {$sum:1}
    }},
    {$match: {count : 2}
  }

], function(err,result){
    result.map(function(doc){
        EspDataModel.aggregate([
                      {
                        $match: { mac: doc._id.mac, hash:doc._id.hash } 
                      },
                      {
                      $group:{
                          mac:"$_id.mac",
                          averageRSSI: {$avg: "$rssi"}
                        }
                      }], function(err,result){
                    console.log(result)
                  })

    })

  })
```

The first aggregate works and effectively select those lines I'm interested in but is there a proper way to match mac and hash of the original collection and compute the average?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `and if the count(*) is equal to 2 then the line is selected.` Can you explain that part again?

Comment: Sure!  I want to group by mac and hash together and if the number of lines with same mac and hash is equal to 2 then I aggregate. Problem is that I loose rssi values.